# Taiwanese Regulations of 433 MHz

Tags: rf, 433mhz, regulations

I'm designing a wireless commercial device to be sold in Taiwan.

I'm looking for transceiver modules, some of them work at 433MHz. However, I'm not clear if the 433 MHz is regulated in Taiwan. Does anyone know if a license is required in to operate short range devices in that band?

Going through the Taiwanese NCC papers (with many of the documentation in traditional Chinese) is not straightforward.

Comment: Have you considered working with a professional company in Taiwan that does approval projects?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't think so, since 433MHz is only designated as ISM in Region 1, but there are some [regulations](https://www.ncc.gov.tw/chinese/files/11070/260_1807_110708_1_C.PDF) that appear to allow a manually operated transmitter that stops transmission within 5 seconds of release of the button (or automatic transmit with bursts of < 5 seconds).

[image]

(machine translation)

> (4.1.1) Operators operating at 314-316MHZ and 433-435MHZ: For manual
> launching equipment, a switch is required. After pressing and
> releasing this switch, it should automatically stop launching within 5
> seconds.  For those with automatic control devices, each launch time
> should be less than 5 seconds

The preceding section header (another machine translation)

[image]

(4.1) Those used to transmit control signals, such as: alarm systems, door openers, remote switches, etc., but not for continuous transmission, such as radio remote control toys  Or send audio, video and data, etc.  Do not use periodic transmission at regular predetermined intervals.  However, for the polling or supervision signal of security or safety business, each transmitter is allowed to transmit at most two times per hour and each transmission shall not exceed 1 second.

Edit: [This](https://www.ncc.gov.tw/english/files/20081/LP0002%20Low-power%20Radio-frequency%20Devices%20Technical%20Regulations.pdf) appears to be the same document in English, as found by Leonardo.

Comment: Thanks to your answer @Spehro I believe I have found the equivalent [document](https://www.ncc.gov.tw/english/files/20081/LP0002%20Low-power%20Radio-frequency%20Devices%20Technical%20Regulations.pdf) in English!

Comment: Sure looks like it. Same document number.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of Google, the offical table of frequency allocation appears to be this one:

https://www.ncc.gov.tw/english/gradation.aspx?site_content_sn=318

It's in English and quite straight-forward. There apparently exists no license-free SRD band around 433MHz. This is usually the case in South East Asia where every country tends to have it's own set of rules. That spectrum is reserved for radiolocation and amateur radio.

I'd contact the authorities or a local test house, describe the application and ask which band it might use. Most likely you need some manner of 3rd party testing.

Answer (score 1):

For the current document in English have a look here: https://www.ncc.gov.tw/english/files/12013/102_968_170120_1.pdf

All other links seem to be dead.

The relevant paragraph appears to be `3.4.2.4` on page 9.